# Email button to generate dynamic url using flask

Tags: python, html, email, flask, jinja2

*First of all I was not really sure how to formulate a proper question due to an insufficient knowledge of webprogramming in general, therefore my apologies.*

I created a Flask app where an email in generated after a button click and the email contains HTML code (similar to http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473810/). Now the email itself also contains a button. Here's what I want to do:

When the email receiver clicks the button in the email, I want to generate an url and have acces to the database similar to what happens in e.g. the following webpage:

**Html** (e.g. validation.html):

```
<body>
    <input type="button" class="validate" onclick="location.href='{{ url_for('validate.afterValidation') }}';" value="Validate" /> 
</body>
```

**Python:**

```
@validate_blueprint.route('/validate/',methods=['GET'])
def afterValidation():
    return render_template('afterValidation.html')
```

So I want to use a similar way for rendering a template after the email button is clicked, using python to acces the database etc. 
How can I achieve this?

Thanks!